# How can CorDapps deal with transitive dependencies

Tags: corda

Currently in v2, if a CorDapp references a module X, which has a transitive dependency to a module Y, such that Y is used by Corda, a potential version conflict can occur if the respective versions of Y for Corda and X differ. An example is the reuse of an existing internal library, containing business and serialisation logic, that depends on `Jackson`.

In this case, the resulting CorDapp packaging and Corda runtime, seem to enforce the version of Y that is relevant for Corda.

If the versions of Y differ sufficiently, we can get such scenarios as X breaking because Y doesn’t support certain types and methods.

Is there a general way that the gradle configuration (or some other mechanism) can be used to restrict the correct version of Y for usage by X, without impacting the Corda runtime?

Answer (score 3):

So I worked this out, and in the process, finally learnt some gradle basics (having come from a maven background). No doubt the following is inelegant and could be generalised better - but it works!

> TLDR: `shadowJar`

## Assumptions

- you're using the current [v2 kotlin cordapp template](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-kotlin)
- the `cordapp` sub module uses dependencies that either they or their dependencies clash against the `Corda` runtime.

## Solution

### 1. add the `shadowJar` reference

In the root `build.gradle` file add the following

`classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:2.0.2'`

to the `buildscript` `dependencies`:

```
buildscript {
// ...
    dependencies {
// ...
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:2.0.2'
    }
}
```

### 2. add `shadowJar` task to the `cordapp`

In the `cordapp` project, apply the `shadowJar` plugin.

> Please Note: I needed to put this before all existing plugins for it to work.

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
// ... etc
```

Then add the invocation parameterisation:

```
tasks {
    shadowJar {
        mergeServiceFiles()

        // Place your shaded packages here!

        relocate 'io.netty', 'shadow.io.netty'
        relocate 'com.fasterxml', 'shadow.com.fasterxml'

        configurations = [project.configurations.compile]
        baseName = jar.baseName + "-" + jar.version
        classifier = null
        version = null
        dependencies {
            include(dependency(".*:.*:.*"))
            exclude(dependency('org.jetbrains.kotlin:.*:.*'))
            exclude(dependency('net.corda:.*:.*'))
            exclude(dependency('org.apache.logging.*:.*:.*'))
            exclude(dependency('org.apache.activemq:.*:.*'))
            exclude(dependency('com.google.*:.*:.*'))
            exclude(dependency('io.reactivex:.*:.*'))
            exclude(dependency('org.bouncycastle.*:.*:.*'))
            exclude(dependency('org.glassfish.*:.*:.*'))
            exclude(dependency('co.paralleluniverse.*:.*:.*'))
            exclude(dependency('co.paralleluniverse.*:.*:.*'))
            exclude(dependency('com.typesafe.*:.*:.*'))
            exclude(dependency('com.esotericsoftware.*:.*:.*'))
            exclude(dependency('org.qpid.*:.*:.*'))
        }
    }
}
```

### 3. Alter the build dependencies

Now change the definition of `deployNodes` to *not* depend on the `jar` task, but instead, depend on the build of each module:

```
task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: [':cordapp-contracts-states:jar', ':cordapp:shadowJar']) {
// ... etc 
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that I've had to exclude more unnecessary dependencies since I made this post. I've added these above. All of this may be easier if Corda could separate out interface and implementation in separate modules. Or if CordFormation can optionally shade cordapp dependencies.