# Corda: Kryo Buffer Underflow

Tags: corda

I'm attempting to connect to a running Corda node via RPC using the Corda Explorer. As soon as I hit login I see this exception:

```
(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1122) core.client.run - AMQ214000: Failed to call onMessage
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Buffer underflow.
Serialization trace:
owningKey (net.corda.core.identity.Party)
value (net.corda.core.utilities.Try$Success)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.require(Input.java:199) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.readVarInt(Input.java:373) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.readInt(Input.java:368) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
```

I've lost several hours on this trying various ideas to both understand the issue and resolve it.

My CordaApp is very standard, is loaded within the node, and I can start flows via the command interface.

I am troubled such a serious issue can occur with little indication of what the issue is at the application level, as the stack trace originates in an Artemis event handler.

The code executing in Explorer when the exception occurs is:

```
 var proxy =
        CordaRPCClient(
                nodeHostAndPort,
                CordaRPCClientConfiguration.DEFAULT.copy(
                        connectionMaxRetryInterval = 10.seconds
                )).start(username, password).proxy
```

The actual exception occurs on this next line:

```
    notaryIdentities = proxy.notaryIdentities()
```

However, if I remove the call to notaryIdentiites a similar kryo exception occurs; which leads me to believe it's a more fundamental issue with the serialisation layer?

There have been no code changes at the application level, so I am totally mystified as to what could be causing this. I have read other questions and answers on here which seem to indicate it is often caused by threading / race conditions surrounding buffer management during serialisation in kyro.

But the fact it has suddenly started to occur is so baffling.

Could the Corda team suggest some possible things for me to check to assist in resolving this issue? Could it be some kind of build/deployment/dependency issue?

I am hoping to resolve this issue today / tomorrow in order to be able to demo the application to management this week, so would really appreciate assistance. After several hours wasted on this I've run out of ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved.
This was due to me adding the CordaApp as a module alongside the main Corda project in IntelliJ, and running explorer using the application | run gradle task from there. When removed the CordaApp module from IntelliJ, the exception does not occur.

I suspect it's some java library clash somewhere.

If anyone can suggest potential conflicts which could have caused this?

Answer (score 0):

Corda 3 requires Guava version 19. Your CorDapp is directly or indirectly depending on a different version of Guava.

When your CorDapp loads, it may randomly replace the Guava version 19 classes with ones from your CorDapp's other version of Guava, causing a `Buffer underflow` exception.

There are currently no easy solutions, but one workaround is shading your JARs. See [How can CorDapps deal with transitive dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48645361/how-can-cordapps-deal-with-transitive-dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue and fixing guava version to 19.0 fixed it for me.

add specific dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: "com.google.guava", name: "guava", version: "19.0"
}
```